# Doctrine2 loading DoctrineExtensions

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I want to use the DAY() and YEAR() functions in my Doctrine2 query builder. But somehow I keep on getting errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT DAY(h.date) AS day FROM Entities\Hit h GROUP BY day in
```

PHP Code:

```
$totalHits = $this->registry->entityManager->getRepository('Entities\Hit')
->createQueryBuilder('h')
->select('DAY(h.date) AS day')
->groupBy('day')
->getQuery()->getResult();`
```

Loading the doctrineExtensions through composer or through the autoloader wouldn't fix it:

```
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', __DIR__.'/../vendor/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions');
$classLoader->register();
```

Am I loading the DoctrineExtensions just wrongly or is there something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Adding:

```
$entityManagerConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Sqlite\Year');
$entityManagerConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('MONTH', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Sqlite\Month');
$entityManagerConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DAY', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Sqlite\Day');
```

solved the problem